# Why is Cybil with Harry in the graveyard after you beat Silent Hill?

Tags: silent-hill

When you finish the game, the title sequence is modified to show Cybil Bennet and Harry together in a graveyard, discovering a baby.  Why, and what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't get the Good+ ending then? Cybil lives (if you save her instead of killing her) and leaves with Harry in the either ending. Cybil being with Harry instead of his wife seems like it might have hinted at a romantic relationship between Cybil and Harry post Silent Hill, but Silent Hill 3 seems to dispute that as she's nowhere to be found.

The baby of course is Heather, and they're probably in the graveyard as a reference to Heather being the rebirth (and reunion) of Alessa and Cheryl in the Good ending. I'm not entirely sure why it appears to be a graveyard in the original intro though--they were supposed to find Cheryl by the side of the road.

All in all it's a reference to the cyclic chain of events before and after Silent Hill, though the replacement of Jodie (Harry's wife, only named in non-game content) with Cybil is slightly odd since canon has neglected her since.